# Create array from JSON - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a JSON file that I would like to create an array from.

Here is the JSON data.

```
{
  "table": {
    "columnNames": ["column1", "column2", "column3", "column4"],
    "columnTypes": ["String", "String", "String", "String"],
    "rows": [
      ["data00", "data01", "data02", "data03"],
      ["data10", "data11", "data12", "data13"],
      ["data20", "data21", "data22", "data23"],
      ["data30", "data31", "data32", "data33"]
     ]
   }
}
```

I need to create an array from the objects in the "rows" section.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!!!

**EDIT**

Would it be possible to create a hash table out of the data in rows?
Also, how would you perform JSON.parse on a json file?
Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do you mean you want to get a single array holding all the values?

```
var rows = [];

for (var i = 0; i < data.table.rows.length; i++) {
    rows.push.apply(rows, data.table.rows[i]);
}
```

See MDN docs for [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) and [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Apply).

This assumes that you've stored the data from your question in a variable `data`. If you only have it as a JSON string, you'll need to convert it with [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

Comment: Would it be possible to create a multi-dimensional array with rows and then the individual data in each row?

Comment: It's already a multidimensional array, just use `data.table.rows` to grab it

Answer (score 2):

JSON is basically javascript already, so once you've [decoded the JSON string](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) back to a native JS data structure, then it'd be a simple matter of doing:

```
var rowsarray = decoded_json.table.rows;
```